# How to perform search and match from a pandas column to create a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame where, there is a string column A. I want to match for specific key words in the list below and create a new column.

[Android, iOS, Windows, Linux, MacOS].

If there is no match from the above list, then the new column value is 'Other'.

| Column_A | New_Column |
| --- | --- |
| Android10 | Android |
| iPhoneiOS 13.5.1 | iOS |
| SamsungAndroid 9 | Android |
| Windows 10 | Windows |
| iPhoneiOS 13.7 | iOS |
| iOS 14.2 | iOS |
| iOS 13.6 | iOS |
| iOS 13.6.1 | iOS |
| iOS 14.1 | iOS |
| iOS 13.4.1 | iOS |
| iOS 14.0.1 | iOS |
| HTCAndroid 8.1.0 | Android |
| Android 8.0.0 | Android |
| iOS 14.0 | iOS |
| Chrome OS | Other |
| Windows 7 | Windows |
| Mac OS X 10.15.4 | MacOS |

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code:

Creating dummy dataframe and list of words to match:

```
terms = ['Android', 'iOS','Windows']
x = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['iPhoneiOS 13.5.1','Android10','SamsungAndroid 9','Windows 10','iPhoneiOS 13.7','iOS 14.2','Test','',np.nan]})
```

Helper function to find strings:

```
def find_str(x):
  for i in terms:
    if i.lower() in x.lower():
        return i
    else:
        return 'Others'

x['Match'] = x['Col1'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: 'Others' if x is None else find_str(x))
print(x)
```

Comment: When, a None (blank) value is encountered it is given the following error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'. I tried to add a condition in the if clause, but it is not helping -         if (i != '') & (i.lower() in x.lower()):
Can you please help?

Comment: I have updated the code, it should work now.